# What do they call those scrolly, curvy elements next to chapter titles?

Tags: typography, terminology, character-styles

There's a name for this, and I even found a web site that helps you create such things for web sites, but I can't find or remember either. The element is on both sides of "Season 2014" :

[image: text embellishments as found on www.bsstc.com.au]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you ask someone in the publishing world what they are called they will point you to what's called a "Chapter Ornament" or a "Book Ornament".  If you want to get further technical on the design process, book designers will refer to them if they are at the beginning of a chapter as a "Chapter Heading Ornament" or at the end of the chapter as a "End of Chapter Ornament".

Some fonts do have ornaments within them and if you reference "[BOOK ORNAMENT](http://www.davidmoratto.com/BOOK-DESIGNER/book-ornament.html)" by David Moratto he has a good write up on it:

> DO BOOK ORNAMENTS PLAY AN IMPORTANT PART IN BOOK DESIGN?
>
> Book ornaments can be described as a book designer tool to
>   further connect a book’s body composition together and enhance the
>   reading experience for the reader. An ornament shouldn’t distract from
>   the content, but rather be an influential silent partner in the
>   background and when noticed should be pleasant to look at.   Ornaments
>   can also provide a characteristic feel to a book.   Ornaments are very
>   specific and embellish the book’s meaning. A floral ornament would
>   enhance a gardening book but would be a distraction in a book about
>   icebergs.

At the bottom of the article he does address some examples of fonts that do have a selection of ornaments, my particular favorites:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

They are also called "flourishes."  One of the definitions of the noun form of "flourish" is "a decoration or embellishment, especially in writing," and one of its synonyms is "ornament".

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, they are called 'embellishments', or smore specifically 'text embellishments'.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll ornament is the term, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had a hierarchy system in my head. How it got there, I haven't a clue. Thus: text (alpha/numeric/punctuation), dingbats (at times, bullets), flourishes or ornaments (your concern), and finally illustrations -- which have, in my mind, a hierarchy of their own.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vignettes), they are called vignettes.

[Stellabooks.com](https://stellabooks.com/page/glossary-of-descriptive-book-terms#:%7E:text=HALF%2DTITLE%20PAGE%20%3D%20Usually%20preceding,the%20start%20of%20a%20chapter.) calls them Headpieces or Tailpieces.

Answer (score -4):

They are called glyphs. They are included with some fonts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77211)

Comment: @Ovaryraptor: This is clearly an attempt to answer the question and not a comment. It may be a wrong answer, but that’s a reason to downvote, not to flag.

Comment: user122969, your answer is not correct. Take a look at this question to learn what a glyph is: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45162/what-is-the-difference-between-glyph-and-font