# What is this design element called?

Tags: illustration, terminology, line-art

On some illustrations, you will see an ornate underline beneath text, with curlicues:

[image]

What is the technical name for this design element?

Comment: That looks like Hollow Knight but based on my google search it's for Elden Ring

Comment: yeah, I found it in an Elden Ring YouTube, and I assumed that they either borrowed it from or were influenced by Hollow Knight

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for can be found here - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24814/what-do-they-call-those-scrolly-curvy-elements-next-to-chapter-titles

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for can be found here - [https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24814/what-do-they-call-those-scrolly-curvy-elements-next-to-chapter-titles](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24814/what-do-they-call-those-scrolly-curvy-elements-next-to-chapter-titles)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These can go by various names, such as: flourishes, ornaments, or scrolls, depending on the look.  A flourish might refer to something more ornate. Ornaments more generally speaking. A scroll shape at its most basic.

For example, these kind of scroll shapes

[image]

Comment: *Ornament* is the "classic" type-catalog term. Random 19th century specimen book, jump to page 642 ( https://www.google.com/books/edition/Desk_Book/zgJQAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=ornament )

Answer (score 7):

I think they are called **Swirls**. And of course, there's different types - like *Floral Swirls* or *Ornate swirls* and such.